# PowerShell: Using already created objects

Tags: powershell

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application

i want to reuse this object when the script runs next time. I don't want to create a new object

Comment: How script is executed? Scheduled task? execute from same powershell console by hand?

Comment: What happens if your script terminates abnormally, or some other process on the system terminates your instance of IE?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to attach to the process with this, check the result of the Windows() method, locate the IE one and then build the correct where clause:

```
$ie = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows() | Where-Object {...}
```